# Transforming inequality constraints into equality constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-distributions, linear-programming

**Intro:** Suppose we want to find whether the feasibility region of this linear programming is non-empty:
$$
(1) \quad 
Ax \leq b\\
\quad \quad C x = 0
$$
Suppose that verifying the feasibility of (1) is computationally very difficult. Instead, verifying the feasibility  of (2) is easier:
$$
(2) \quad 
Ax \leq b\\
\quad \quad C x \leq  0
$$
As discussed by many other questions in this forum (e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/689645/relax-equality-into-inequality-in-convex-problem) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/805409/convex-optimization-affine-equality-constraints-into-inequality-constraints)),   (2) being feasible does not imply (1) being feasible, in general. However, I wonder whether in my specific example this can be claimed.
In what follows, I first introduce the notation, second I present my questions, and third I conclude with some final thoughts and clarifications.

---

**Notation:** Consider a **function** $F: \bar{\mathbb{R}}^3\rightarrow [0,1]$, where $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ is the extended real line. For any two vectors $x\equiv (x_1,x_2,x_3)\in \bar{\mathbb{R}}^3$ and $y\equiv (y_1,y_2,y_3)\in \bar{\mathbb{R}}^3$, define the volume of the box  $[x_1,y_1]\times [x_2,y_2]\times [x_3,y_3]$ as:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\mbox{Vol}_F(x,y)\equiv \sum_{v\in \text{vert}(x,y)}F(v)*sgn_{x,y}(v)
\end{aligned}
$$

where:

- $\text{vert}(x,y)$ is the collection of $2^3$ vertices of the box $[x_1,y_1]\times [x_2,y_2]\times [x_3,y_3]$;
- a generic vertex from $\text{vert}(x,y)$ is denoted by $v\equiv (v_1,v_2,v_3)$;
- $sgn_{x,y}(v)$ is equal to $1$ if $v_l=x_l$ for an even number of $l\in \{1,2,3\}$, and equal to $-1$ otherwise;
- 0 is considered even.

---

**Assumption:** Fix $(u,t)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $(p_1,p_2,p_3)\in [0,1]^3$ such that $p_1+p_2+p_3=1$. Suppose that exists $F: \bar{\mathbb{R}}^3\rightarrow [0,1]$ such that
$$
(*)\quad 
\begin{cases}
(1) \quad F(\infty,\infty,\infty)=1\\
(2) \quad F(x)=0 \text{ when $x\in\bar{\mathbb{R}}^3$ has at least one component equal to $-\infty$}\\
(3) \quad F(a,\infty,\infty)+F(-a, \infty, \infty)=1 \text{ for each $a\in \mathbb{R}$}\\
(4) \quad F(\infty,a, \infty)+F( \infty,-a, \infty)=1 \text{ for each $a\in \mathbb{R}$}\\
(5) \quad F( \infty,\infty,a)+F( \infty, \infty,-a)=1 \text{ for each $a\in \mathbb{R}$}\\
---------------------------------\\
(6) \quad\mbox{Vol}_F((-t,-\infty,u-t),(\infty,\infty,\infty))=p_1\\
(7) \quad\mbox{Vol}_F((-\infty,-u,-\infty),(\infty,\infty,u-t))=p_2\\
(8) \quad\mbox{Vol}_F((-\infty,-\infty,-\infty),(-t,-u,\infty))=p_3\\
---------------------------------\\
(9) \quad \mbox{Vol}_F(x,y)\geq 0 \text{ for each $x\in\bar{\mathbb{R}}^3$ and $y\in \bar{\mathbb{R}}^3$ with $x \leq y$ component-wise}
\end{cases}
$$

Note that $(*)$ is an **infinite dimensional linear program**, where the unknown is the function $F$.

---

**Claim:** The above Assumption implies that there exists $G:\bar{\mathbb{R}}^3\rightarrow [0,1]$ such that
$$
(**) \quad \begin{cases}
(10) \quad G(\infty,\infty,\infty)=1\\
(11) \quad G(x)=0 \text{ when $x\in\bar{\mathbb{R}}^3$ has at least one component equal to $-\infty$}\\
(12) \quad G(a,\infty,\infty)+G(-a, \infty, \infty)=1 \text{ for each $a\in \mathbb{R}$}\\
(13) \quad G(\infty,a, \infty)+G( \infty,-a, \infty)=1 \text{ for each $a\in \mathbb{R}$}\\
(14) \quad G( \infty,\infty,a)+G( \infty, \infty,-a)=1 \text{ for each $a\in \mathbb{R}$}\\
---------------------------------\\
(15) \quad\mbox{Vol}_G((-t,-\infty,u-t),(\infty,\infty,\infty))=p_1\\
(16) \quad\mbox{Vol}_G((-\infty,-u,-\infty),(\infty,\infty,u-t))=p_2\\
(17) \quad\mbox{Vol}_G((-\infty,-\infty,-\infty),(-t,-u,\infty))=p_3\\
---------------------------------\\
(18) \quad \mbox{Vol}_G(x,y)\geq 0 \text{ for each $x\in\bar{\mathbb{R}}^3$ and $y\in \bar{\mathbb{R}}^3$ with $x \leq y$ component-wise}\\
---------------------------------\\
(19) \quad \mbox{Vol}_G((a,-\infty,-\infty),(\infty,b,a-b))= 0 \text{ for each $(a,b)\in {\mathbb{R}}^2$}\\
(20) \quad \mbox{Vol}_G(( -\infty,b, a-b),(a,\infty,\infty))= 0 \text{ for each $(a,b)\in {\mathbb{R}}^2$}\\
\end{cases}
$$

---

**Question**: How can I prove the claim?

---

**Some thoughts:** For those of you familiar with probability, $F$ is a cumulative distribution function. In particular, (9) guarantees that $F$ is non-decreasing. Instead (3)-(5) require the marginal distributions of $F$ to be symmetric around zero.

I have done some simulations (in finite dimension, though!) and it seems to me that the claim is correct. If you can think of a counterexample, please advise. Otherwise, I would like your help with the proof.

Note that:

- (1)-(9) is equal to (10)-(18).
- (15), (16), (17) imply that
  $$
  \begin{aligned}
  &(21) \quad \mbox{Vol}_G((-t,-\infty,-\infty),(\infty,-u,u-t))= 0\\
  &(22) \quad \mbox{Vol}_G(( -\infty,-u, u-t),(-t,\infty,\infty))= 0
  \end{aligned}
  $$
  Observe that (21) and (22) are part of (19) and (20).
- **(19) and (20) require some of the inequalities in (18) to hold as equalities**. This is what it makes it hard to do the proof, as mentioned at the beginning.
- **A strategy to prove the above claim could be to show that: first, if the feasible set of $(*)$ is non-empty, then it is a polytope; second, (19)-(20) are always boundaries of such polytope. How can I do that?**

Comment: In (7) and (8), how are you defining $a - b$ in the extended real plane?

Comment: @JohnD Would you have any suggestions on how to approach the  problem? For instance, I wonder whether a strategy to prove the above claim could be to show that: first, if the feasible set of (∗) is non-empty, then it is a polytope; second, (19)-(20) are always boundaries of such polytope. What are your thoughts?

Comment: Dear TEX, have a look at the definition of linear programming on Wolfram Alpha. It is neither of importance to define such functions nor is it a matter if this corresponding problem is unique or not as long as You have the matrices and the vector. It is rather like in Your intro. You modify the general linear programming problem and make use of decorations that seem uninteresting to get the solution to a problem. Linear programming is insensitive to context and linear functions are matrices time the variables. Linear programming problems have usually solutions in the finite range.

Comment: Taking $Cx = 0$ as a constraint. Let the cost function be $F(x)$. Add a slack variable $s$ s.t. $Cx + s = 0$ and add it to the cost $F(x) +Ms$ with a large multiplier $M$. This will give the easier feasible solution $Cx \le 0$ and minimize $s$.

Comment: If $Cx$ is the cost function then convert it to a constraint $Cx + s = 0$ and minimize the cost function $F = s$. If $s_{min} = 0$ then there is a solution else there is not.

Comment: Can you rewrite this in my notation? I'm not sure I follow